# How can I print different charts for different data with Excel or VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I am trying to print one graph for each row/table, the graphs should keep the same format, only the data should change among graphs. I need to do it for about 120 rows/tables so I would like to avoid doing it manually, also, I would prefer not to use the sparklines as its format is not appropriate for the purpose of the analysis.

I have tried to use a dynamic chart with the combo button but when I change the filtered line, every copied graph changes as well, making it impossible to have at the same time graphs showing different rows - one solution may be pasting it as image but it is not optimal as I would like to check the data for each graph if needed.

Below I show the example for two different "items", in the original dataset there are about 350/400 rows and about 120 "items", every 3 rows create one graph.

[image]

The graphs I have created manually are: (one for each 3 rows)

for "item" xxx:

**[image: strong text]**

For "item" yyy:

[image]

I need to print this type of graph for other different ~120 "items", all at once.

In terms of showing the format of the chart, see the below for the first graph:
[image]

The blank is:

[image]

The second quartile is:

[image]

The third quartile:

[image]

and the "item", which is the black point in the graph:

[image]

Same reasoning for the second graph, but considering the three rows with yyy.

I hope you can help me!

Sorry for the big amount of images, but I wanted it to be clear!

Thank you in advance!

Best,
Ema

Comment: VBA is the right direction for this problem, especially with the number of graphs you need to produce. I would suggest recording a macro with the steps you take to create a single graph, then go and edit that macro so it can loop over all the rows in your data set. Start with that and come back with specific questions when you have the VBA code when you start to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to create a typical procedure for creating a chart and use parameters to iterate over the sheet.

```
Sub makeCharts()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cht As Chart, Shp As Shape
    Dim obj As ChartObject
    Dim Target As Range, rngShp As Range
    Dim r As Long, n As Long, i As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each obj In Ws.ChartObjects
        obj.Delete
    Next

    r = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    n = 1
    For i = 3 To r Step 3

        Set rngShp = Ws.Range("k" & n).Resize(10, 8)
        Set Target = Ws.Range("a" & i)
        Set Shp = Ws.Shapes.AddChart
        With Shp
            .Top = rngShp.Top
            .Left = rngShp.Left
            .Width = rngShp.Width
            .Height = rngShp.Height
        End With
        Set Cht = Shp.Chart
        setCharts Target, Cht
        n = n + 12
    Next i
End Sub


Sub setCharts(Target As Range, Cht As Chart)
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim vColor
    Dim i As Integer

    vColor = Array(RGB(246, 246, 246), RGB(255, 224, 140), RGB(47, 157, 39), RGB(0, 0, 0))

    With Cht
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .HasLegend = False
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = Target.Value
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "OCF Percentiles"
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 20
        For Each Srs In .SeriesCollection
            Srs.Delete
        Next Srs

        For i = 0 To 2
            Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Srs
                .Values = Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(3).Offset(0, i)
                .XValues = Array("A", "D", "I")
                .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vColor(i)
                If i = 0 Then
                    .Format.Fill.Transparency = 1 '<~~~~~ Transparency was adjusted
                End If
            End With
        Next i
        Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With Srs
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .Values = Target.Offset(0, 4).Resize(1, 3)
            .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleSquare
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = vColor(3) 'vbBlack
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

### Result image

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dy.Lee ! do you know how I can set the "blank" bar as transparent instead of light grey?

Comment: @EmanuelaMasucci, .Format.Fill.Transparency = 1  ,  I edited my answer.